# How to show additional information on github checks from Google Cloud build github App

Tags: google-cloud-build, github-check-run

I configured github checks with the Google Cloud Build Github App and now I would like to know if I can show any additional custom data on the github check or in the github check detail page.

[image: Github Image]

Currently, there isn't much useful information when a build fails:
[image: Failed github cloud build check]

Comment: I would love to see more information and possibly be able to have a check on each of the steps along the way or be able to set some check myself.

Comment: @GustavoHoirisch Yes! (I even wrote a blog [post](https://medium.com/kunder/how-to-integrate-github-checks-with-google-cloud-build-and-python-tests-5fd05c4f3dff) about this!)